# Month Wise Sales Using Mongo Query?

Tags: mongodb

This  Is My Sales Data
This is my first post.so please ignore if I am doing any mistake.My question is how can get month wise sales data from this table.

```
Invoice Amount         Invoice Date

  9870            2014-06-26 18:30:00.000Z
  15330           2014-06-04 18:30:00.000Z
  44354           2014-08-15 18:30:00.000Z
  54400           2014-07-22 18:30:00.000Z
```

Comment: take a look at the $group operator in MongoDB Aggregation framework

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to group all invoices that are on the same month and sum up the amounts. This can be done using [MongoDB's aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/).

For this, you will first need to extract the month from the date field, using [MongoDB's aggregation date operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/), and then group on that value, summing up the invoice values in the process, in order to get per-month totals.

A query would look something like (you might need to adjust the collection and field names):

```
db.invoices.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            'amount': true,
            'month': { $month: '$date' },
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$month',
            total: { '$sum': '$amount' }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: and how exactly will this group based on a month?

Comment: I misread the question but now I've updated my answer. Sorry about that!